# IP coming as long string instead of classic IP format

Tags: php, sql, ip

If this was already asked I do apologize but I searched for a good two hours about this.

So I have a website and on it I have an admin panel that logs all my admin's actions, when doing so I grab their IP just in case the session bugs and deletes the name variable. However I've noticed some people have IPS' such as AT&T that seemingly encrypt your IP address. The IP address comes out looking like this:

```
2600:1003:b109:9b8a:70c7:3b0e:5fd3:d8f3
```

Does anyone know how to convert it to be back like this:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I've noticed that sites like whatsmyip.org do this.

Edit after reply: I feel stupid, I didn't even think about this being an IPv6 Address. Thanks for pointing it out everyone.

Comment: That *long string* is an [IPV6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address. It's nothing to do with being encrypted.

Comment: @KenWhite I get the actual IPs from most request however.

Comment: @JacobH Ill check thanks.

Comment: They are both "actual IPs". One is a newer format (IPv6) and one is older (IPv4). You should design your app to handle both formats.

Comment: What you get from *most request* is irrelevant. An IPV6 address is perfectly valid, and is not encrypted. Read the Wikipedia article I linked.

Answer (score 2):

That's not encrypted.  That's the IP address.  It's an IPv6 address.

Your web hosting supports both IPv4 and IPv6 addressing, which is why you'll see a mix of these in your logs.

Comment: And eventually, *everyone* will be coming via IPv6.

Comment: @ceejayoz We can only hope.  :-)  I had to help someone with IPX/SPX a couple weeks ago.